# Sling scheduler method refactor

Tags: java, refactoring, aem, sling

I have deprecated method [Scheduler.addPeriodicJob](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/kr/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/org/apache/sling/commons/scheduler/Scheduler.html#addPeriodicJob(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Map,%20long,%20boolean)). I want to refactor my code and replace it with
[Scheduler.schedule](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/kr/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/org/apache/sling/commons/scheduler/Scheduler.html#schedule(java.lang.Object,%20org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.ScheduleOptions)) How to do it with [ScheduleOptions](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/kr/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/org/apache/sling/commons/scheduler/ScheduleOptions.html) Interface and how to pass values by it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this page](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/commons/scheduler/class-use/ScheduleOptions.html).
It looks you need to replace each call like:

```
Scheduler s;
s.addPeriodicJob(name, job, config, period, canRunConcurrently);
```

with something like

```
Scheduler s;
ScheduleOptions so = Scheduler.NOW(times, period); // times == -1 for endless
so.canRunConcurrently(canRunConcurrently);
so.config(config);
so.name(name);
s.schedule(job, so);
```

Comment: Oh you were looking for that simple answer? Alright.

Answer (score 3):

This solution should be used if you have a lot of references to fix.

## Emulate Scheduler interface so you can refactor its usage

You could create a class `org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.Scheduler` in your codebase and declare the old and new methods:

```
public class Scheduler {

  @Deprecated
  public void addPeriodicJob(String name,
                             Object job,
                             Map<String,Serializable> config,
                             long period,
                             boolean canRunConcurrently)
                  throws Exception {
      ScheduleOptions options = NOW(-1, period)
          .name(name)
          .config(config)
          .canRunConcurrently(canRunConcurrently);
      schedule(job, options);
  }

  public boolean schedule(Object job, ScheduleOptions options) {
      // dummy placeholder to let the code compile
      return false;
  }
}
```

(You may need to implement all the methods of `Scheduler` interface required to make your code compile and let the refactoring work as expected)

Then, inline the `addPeriodicJob()` method with your IDE's refactoring tools.
Finally, remove the `Scheduler` class that you created in your codebase.
All your code should should have been migrated now!

### Before committing

You finally have a cleanup step in your hands where you ***must*** (I can't emphasize this enough):

1. review all the changes
2. test
3. commit

## Possibly additional cleanup

Then you should probably remove all unnecessary code, or default values.

For example, my test sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
    scheduler.addPeriodicJob("name", new Object(), Collections.EMPTY_MAP, 10, false);
}
```

Ended up like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
    ScheduleOptions options = scheduler.NOW(-1, (long) 10).name("name").config((Map<String, Serializable>) Collections.EMPTY_MAP).canRunConcurrently(false);
    scheduler.schedule(new Object(), options);
}
```

You could do some reformatting and cleaning up to end here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
    ScheduleOptions options = scheduler
        .NOW(-1, 10)
        .name("name")
        .config(Collections.EMPTY_MAP)
        .canRunConcurrently(false);
    scheduler.schedule(new Object(), options);
}
```

And if you removed code that sets default or meaningless values, you could even end up with (I suppose, because I know nothing about sling):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
    scheduler.schedule(new Object(), scheduler.NOW(-1, 10));
}
```